# VSCode Extension REST calls not working

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to build an extension for Visual Studio Code and I seem to be running into issues making a POST request from inside the extension.  I've created a script that submits a multipart-form to upload a file to a local running server.  I've tested the API via Postman and it works fine.  I can actually run the script from a Command Prompt window with Node and it submits the request fine.  But that exact same script running as part of a VSCode extension (In Debug mode) either cannot make the request at all in some cases, or it doesn't seem to properly submit the form.

Here is the code in the script

```js
//Sync a package to the AEM server
const PACKAGEMGR_PATH = "/crx/packmgr/service.jsp";
const fs = require('fs');
var rp = require('request-promise');
rp.debug = true;
const parseUrl = require('url').parse

class Sync {
    syncPackage(packagePath, host, port, username, password) {
        var url = parseUrl("http://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + host + ":" + port + PACKAGEMGR_PATH);
        var auth = Buffer.from(url.auth).toString('base64');
        var cleanURL = "http://" + url.host + url.path;
        console.log('Basic ' + auth);
        console.log(cleanURL);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            rp({uri: "http://localhost:3000", formData: {
                "file": fs.createReadStream(packagePath),
                "force": "true",
                "install": "true",
                "name": "file"
            }, method: "POST", headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth}}).then((resp) => {
                console.log(resp);
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            })
        });
    }
}

module.exports = new Sync();
```

Now with the example above, the request will make it to the server, but the server can't comprehend the form data and acts as if I sent an empty form.

So to test what data was being sent, I set up a local express echo server on localhost:3000.  Again, from command line, running the script above worked fine and my echo server was able to read the form and spit it back to me.

However, running in VSCode Extension Debug mode, I get this error when trying to post the form:
RequestError: Error: write ECONNRESET

So, is there something special I have to do to get HTTP requests working properly from a VSCode Extension?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see you have some syntax issue in the code, double check the documentation.

To use request-promise with `json` data

```
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://api.posttestserver.com/post',
    body: {
        some: 'payload'
    },
    json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
};

rp(options)
    .then(function (parsedBody) {
        // POST succeeded...
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // POST failed...
    });
```

But if you want to send the request as form data use this format

```
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://posttestserver.com/post.php',
    form: {
        // Like <input type="text" name="name">
        name: 'Josh'
    },
    headers: {
        /* 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' */ // Is set automatically
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm not using JSON, as well "form" is not meant for multipart/form-data which is what I am using.  Again, this script runs 100% fine in Node in a Command Prompt.  The issue only occurs when running as part of a Visual Studio Code extension.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and was able to confirm it is only a problem with the VSCode extension --- browser and other requests are successful as normal.

Go to your express server and add 'localhost' to this line:

```
app.listen(PORT, () => {console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)})
```

like so:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const PORT = 3001
app.listen(PORT, 'localhost', () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)
})
```